# ASP.Net: How to prevent runpage in _PageStart?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-membership, roles, websecurity

in `_PageStart.[vb/cs]html` how to prevent to running requested page?

#### example:

in `_PageStart` you check the roles of authenticated user and if is not in your special role, a message shown **instead of** running page?

#### my code in `_PageStart.vbhtml`

```
@Code
If Roles.IsUserInRole("admin") Or Roles.IsUserInRole("users") Then
    RunPage()
Else
    @RenderPage("~/wtools/_inlineError.vbhtml", "401")
End If
End Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse condition, and remove **else** part

```
If Not Roles.IsUserInRole("admin") And Not Roles.IsUserInRole("users") Then
    Response.StatusCode = 401
    Response.Redirect("~/wtools/_inlineError.vbhtml", True)
End If
```

Comment: No, RunPage() Runs after these lines

Comment: i would not use redirect, because url is changed!

Comment: You need to clarify: if you need to prevent from displaying rest of the page or not displaying it at all.